# Toggle & overlap content in jQuery

Tags: overlap

First forgive my ignorance about web programming, I'm learning on the fly.

I have a menu with three buttons (photography, video and studio) that on click show hiden elements:

- photography - show a submenu
- video - show a submenu
- studio - shows some text

They also show a fullscreem transparency element which highlight the hidden elements on the website page.

Everything works perfectly: when I click on the first button (photography) the submenu drops down with the transparency but if right after I click on the next button, the video submenu shows but the transparency disappears and the photography submenu is still down, overlapping the current one.

Is there any way to deactivate the rest of the effects when activating the current effect?

Thanks and hope I could be clear enough.

HTML:

```
<div class="submenu" id="transparencia"></div>


<div class="menu" id="photography"><a href="">Photography</a></div>
<div class="menu" id="video"><a href="">Video</a></div>
<div class="menu" id="studio"><a href="">Studio</a></div>
<div class="menu" id="blog"><a href="http://whitedogstudio.tumblr.com/" target="_blank">Blog</a>    
</div>

<!-- photography -->

<div  class="submenu1" id="submenu1"><a href="">D-due</a></div>
<div  class="submenu1" id="submenu2"><a href="">Fabrege</a></div>
<div  class="submenu1" id="submenu3"><a href="">Rachael Antonio S/S 12</a></div>
<div  class="submenu1" id="submenu4"><a href="">Frankie Magazine</a></div>
<div  class="submenu1" id="submenu5"><a href="">Rachael Antonio</a></div>
<div  class="submenu1" id="submenu6"><a href="">Red Bull Backstage Fashion Show</a></div>
<div  class="submenu1" id="submenu7"><a href="">D-due Polaorids</a></div>
<div  class="submenu1" id="submenu8"><a href="">D-due</a></div>
<div  class="submenu1" id="submenu9"><a href="">Bargain</a></div>


<!-- video -->

<div  class="submenu2" id="submenu1"><a href="">D-due</a></div>
<div  class="submenu2" id="submenu2"><a href="">Fabrege</a></div>
<div  class="submenu2" id="submenu3"><a href="">Rachael Antonio S/S 12</a></div>
<div  class="submenu2" id="submenu4"><a href="">Frankie Magazine</a></div>
<div  class="submenu2" id="submenu5"><a href="">Rachael Antonio</a></div>
<div  class="submenu2" id="submenu6"><a href="">Red Bull Backstage Fashion Show</a></div>
<div  class="submenu2" id="submenu7"><a href="">D-due Polaorids</a></div>
<div  class="submenu2" id="submenu8"><a href="">D-due</a></div>
<div  class="submenu2" id="submenu9"><a href="">Bargain</a></div>

<!-- studio -->

<div  class="submenu3" id="about" align="center">
<p>text, text, text,text, text, text,text, text, text
</p>
</div>
```

JS/jQuery/jQuery UI/

```
<script>
$( "#photography" ).click(function() {
$( ".submenu1" ).toggle("fast","linear");
$( "#transparencia" ).toggle();
return false;
 });

 $( "#video" ).click(function() {
$( ".submenu2" ).toggle("fast","linear");
$( "#transparencia" ).toggle();
return false;

 });

 $( "#studio" ).click(function() {
$( ".submenu3" ).toggle("fast","linear");
$( "#transparencia" ).toggle();
return false;
 });

</script>


</body>
enter code here
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FC6;
  font-family: helvetica, "Helvetica Neue";
}


.menu{
position: fixed;
top:30px;
width:300px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
z-index:3;
border:none;

}
#photography{   left:130px;}
#video{         left:230px;}
#studio{        left:290px;}
#blog{          left:355px;}

.submenu1{
display:none;
position: fixed;
left:130px;
width:180px;
padding:15px;
height:200px;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 11px;
font-style: normal;
z-index:3;
border:none;
color:#333;
}

.submenu2{
display:none;
position: fixed;
left:230px;
width:180px;
padding:15px;
height:200px;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 11px;
font-style: normal;
z-index:3;
border:none;
color:#333;
}

#submenu1{  top:60px;}
#submenu2{  top:80px;}
#submenu3{  top:100px;}
#submenu4{  top:120px;}
#submenu5{  top:140px;}
#submenu6{  top:160px;}
#submenu7{  top:180px;}
#submenu8{  top:200px;}
#submenu9{  top:220px;}


#transparencia {
display:none;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-image: url(../others/fondo.png);
z-index:2;
color: #FFF;
}

.submenu3{
display:none;
position: fixed;
top:90px;
left:285px;
text-align:justify;
float:left;
width:450px;    
padding:15px;
padding-top:10px;
z-index:3;
line-height:25px;
font-size:12px;
color: #000;
font-weight:100;
border:none;
}



a:link {        color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
a:visited {     color: #000;text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {       color: #000;}
a:active {      text-decoration: none;font-weight:none;}

.linkStyle2 a {         color: #999;text-decoration: none;}
.linkStyle2 a:link {    color: #999;text-decoration: none;}
.linkStyle2 a:visited { color: #999;text-decoration: none;}
.linkStyle2 a:hover {   color: #000;text-decoration: none;}
.linkStyle2 a:active {  text-decoration: none;}

.linkStyle3 a {         color: #000;text-decoration: none;}
.linkStyle3 a:link {    color: #000;text-decoration: none;}
.linkStyle3 a:visited { color: #000;text-decoration: none;}
.linkStyle3 a:hover {   color: #CCC;text-decoration: none;}
.linkStyle3 a:active {  text-decoration: none;}
```